# What is the legally required notice period in the UK if I don't have a contract?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I've been working for a UK-based company for the last 18 months. When I joined I accepted a permanent, salaried position. Had I signed a contract the contractual notice period or statutory notice period would apply. However no contract has ever been presented or signed, even when I chased it.

**How much notice am I legally required to give without a contract?**

Comment: To the down voter, drive by down votes don't help new members of the community - please leave a reason

Comment: Retitled. Dropped ranting language and most of the fluff as it's not relevant. The core question is useful and on-topic as something any manager or small-business owner in the UK should know.

Comment: +1 to the edited version, as it is a clear, answerable, reasonable question in it's current state.

Comment: Do you have an employee handbook? Notice periods are often defined in those.

Comment: Why is this closed as seeking legal advice?  It's a question about *what the law is*, not about *how to apply the law*. That's on-topic.

Comment: I agree with @Lilienthal this is knowledge that any business owner or hr will know

Comment: @Neuromancer If you want to get the question reopened you'll probably have to create a meta thread for it considering its age.

Answer (score 3):

UK statutory notice period after 1 month of employment is 1 week.

> **2. Giving notice**
>
> You must give at least a week’s notice if you’ve been in your job for more than a month.

https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice/giving-notice

The fact that you do not have a written contract does not negate this statutory requirement:

> **Accepting a contract**
>
> As soon as someone accepts a job offer they have a contract with their employer. An employment contract doesn’t have to be written down.

https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/overview

Comment: I have no employment contract. Does the act of working there and receiving regular payments constitute employment?

Comment: @Donogst As soon as you accept the job offer, you have a contract - the contract doesnt need to be written down: https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/overview

Comment: Your source mentions nothing of "up to 2 years". I'd also suggest including that comment in the answer as it's vital to its validity. Right now this is barely more than a link so while a single-line answer is fine for a basic question I'd also encourage you to include the relevant section from the source.

Comment: May be confused with https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights/notice-periods which defines the notice periods that the _employer_ must give, which may be longer: 1 week if employed 1 month to 2 years, 1 week for every full year up to 12 years, 12 weeks if employed for more than 12 years.

Comment: I think the statutory requirement for the employee with nothing mentioned in the contract is actually 1 week notice period after 1 month working (no matter how long you work). In my experience, I've never seen a contract that didn't require something longer for both sides. The good thing compared to the USA is that an employee who worked for say four years can afford to give the employer four weeks notice without fear of being fired immediately or early.

Comment: @user54580 yes you do

Answer (score 2):

> **How much notice am I legally required to give without a contract?**

If there is no written contract that you have signed then statutory minima apply. You should note that many types of legally binding contract can be verbal rather than in writing.

According to the [Employment Rights Act 1996]:(http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/part/IX/crossheading/minimum-period-of-notice)

> ## Rights of employer and employee to minimum notice.
>
> (1) **The notice required to be given by an employer** to terminate the
>   contract of employment of a person who has been continuously employed
>   for one month or more—
>
> (a)is not less than one week’s notice if his period of continuous
>   employment is less than two years,
>
> (b)is not less than one week’s notice for each year of continuous
>   employment if his period of continuous employment is two years or more
>   but less than twelve years, and
>
> (c)is not less than twelve weeks’ notice if his period of continuous
>   employment is twelve years or more.
>
> (2) **The notice required to be given by an employee** who has been
>   continuously employed for one month or more to terminate his contract
>   of employment is not less than one week.
>
> (3)Any provision for shorter notice in any contract of employment with
>   a person who has been continuously employed for one month or more has
>   effect subject to subsections (1) and (2); but this section does not
>   prevent either party from waiving his right to notice on any occasion
>   or from accepting a payment in lieu of notice.
>
> (4)Any contract of employment of a person who has been continuously
>   employed for three months or more which is a contract for a term
>   certain of one month or less shall have effect as if it were for an
>   indefinite period; and, accordingly, subsections (1) and (2) apply to
>   the contract.